# how to pass php array fetch from database to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php

I am using

```
var selectOpt = new Array("Pune","Karad","Kolhapur","Satara","Sangli");
```

But want to pass array fetch from database.

Comment: Im using var selectOpt =<?php echo json_encode($result_array); ?>; but not giving proper output.output is like [object]

Comment: define 'not giving proper output'

Comment: You need to parse the JSON object before you can use it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: im using  array directly from database not manually...parseJSON is not working for me

Comment: parseJSON should be used on the clientisde. so var selectOpt = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>');

Comment: still giving output as [object Object] after using jsonparse

Comment: well, we need your code to actually help debugging

Answer (score 0):

just check below code, work fine for me.

```
<div id="div1">
</div>
<?php
$resultArray = array("Pune","Karad","Kolhapur","Satara","Sangli");
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var selectOpt =<?php echo json_encode($resultArray); ?>;

for(var i=0;i<selectOpt.length;i++)
{
document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML += selectOpt[i]+"<br>";
}
</script>
```